# History in calculator with photos instead of signs

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I have code to display the history in the calculator but the signs (+, -, ×, ÷) are taken from the "case" (Photo 1)

[image: **Photo 1**]

How can I make it so that in the history the signs (+, -, ×, ÷) are displayed by the pictures I have set (Photo 2)

[image: **Photo 2**]

```
@IBAction func equalitySignPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if stillTyping {
        secondOperand = currentInput
    }
    dotIsPlaced = false

    addHistory(text: operationSign + displayResultLabel.text!)

    switch operationSign {

    case "+":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 + $1}
    case "-":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 - $1}
    case "×":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 * $1}
    case "÷":
        if secondOperand == 0 {
            Error.text = NSLocalizedString("Division by Zero", comment: "")
            break
        } else {
            operateWithTwoOperands{$0 / $1}
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

Add History:

```
func addHistory(text: String){
    //Add text
    resultLabelText.text =  resultLabelText.text! + "" + text
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No images or attributed strings are needed. You can use the Unicode character `⃣` (U+20E3 - Combining Enclosing Keycap) with the various math symbols: `+`, `-`, `×`, `÷`. `=`.

Putting these together gives: `+⃣`, `-⃣`, `×⃣`, `÷⃣`, `=⃣`.

Comment: I can not understand how this can be realized?

Comment: Just put these symbols in your code and display them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSAttributedString` when displaying your history entries. An attributed string can contain images, see for instance https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-insert-images-into-an-attributed-string-with-nstextattachment